# Erase figure's part that is under another figure

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

There is my code:

```
    /* Health */
context.globalAlpha = .5;
context.fillStyle   = "#c0392b";
context.fillRect( 50, 35, 100, 10 );
context.globalAlpha = 1;
context.fillStyle   = "#c0392b";
context.fillRect( 50, 35, hero.statistics.health, 10 );
context.globalAlpha = 1;
context.fillStyle   = "#e74c3c";
context.fillText( hero.statistics.health + "%", 122, 44 );

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo( 150, 45 );
context.lineTo( 150, 35 );
context.lineTo( 140, 35 );
context.closePath();
context.fill();

    /* Poison */
context.globalAlpha = .5;
context.fillStyle   = "#27ae60";
context.fillRect( 50, 47, 100, 10 );
context.globalAlpha = 1;
context.fillStyle   = "#27ae60";
context.fillRect( 50, 47, hero.statistics.poison, 10 );
context.globalAlpha = 1;
context.fillStyle   = "#2ecc71";
context.fillText( hero.statistics.poison + "%", 122, 56 );

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo( 150, 57 );
context.lineTo( 150, 47 );
context.lineTo( 140, 47 );
context.closePath();
context.fill();

    /* Experience */
context.globalAlpha = .5;
context.fillStyle   = "#f1c40f";
context.fillRect( 50, 59, 100, 5 );
context.globalAlpha = 1;
context.fillStyle   = "#f1c40f";
context.fillRect( 50, 59, hero.statistics.experience, 5 );

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo( 150, 69 );
context.lineTo( 150, 59 );
context.lineTo( 140, 59 );
context.closePath();
context.fill();
```

... It give me this: (without the face)

### [image]

How can I erase the part of rectangle that is under the triangle and after erase triangles? I can't set triangles color to black because the background change.

I want change this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Without coloring triangles to black.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what you need?

Comment: No problem, I will add more images in 2 minutes.

Comment: Basically, you redraw everything.  Once you draw an object to the canvas, it is no longer an individual object, but simply part of the canvas.  For example, if you need to change the color of the triangle, you would draw a new triangle over the old one using the new color.

Comment: I know that, but there, I must draw rectangles and erase the part under the triangle. I can't change the triangle color to black (that give similar effect) because the background isn't everytime black.

So I have to erase those parts or directly draw those rectangles, but it looks difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a clipping region to restrict your drawing to your “corner-cut-rect”

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/j2dKz/

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");


    drawBar(50,35,100,10,10,"#c0392b","#e74c3c",75);
    drawBar(50,50,100,10,10,"#27ae60","#2ecc71",35);
    drawBar(50,65,100,10,10,"#f1c40f","#f1c40f",50);

    function drawBar(x,y,w,h,corner,fill1,fill2,percent){

        // create a clipping path 
        // with the right corner cut out

        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x+w-corner,y);
        ctx.lineTo(x+w,y+h);
        ctx.lineTo(x,y+h);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clip();

        // do some fills
        // all fills will be restricted to the clip

        ctx.globalAlpha=.5;
        ctx.fillStyle=fill1;
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
        ctx.globalAlpha=1;
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,percent,h);
        ctx.fillStyle=fill2;
        ctx.fillText(percent+"%",x+w-28,y+h-1);
        ctx.restore();

    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```